# How to find the staff that have taught more than 2 units

Tags: sql

How can I write to query that shows the staff that have taught more than 1 unit?

**Here are tables and columns**

```
Staff (Staff_id, StaffName, Position, Gender)

Taught_by (Unit_code, Staff_id, weekday)

Student (Student_id, Student_name, Address, Gender)

TuteGroup (TuteGroup_code, Unit_code, DayHrCode, Room_Nr)

TuteGroup_List (TuteGroup_code, Student_id)
```

Comment: This is not a `fix my homework` site. Show us what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `Staff` and `Taught_by`, group by `Staff_id` and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT s.Staff_id, s.StaffName
FROM Staff s INNER JOIN Taught_by t
ON t.Staff_id = s.Staff_id
GROUP BY s.Staff_id, s.StaffName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Unit_code) > 2
```